# Bottomsheet ListView showing only 1 item

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter, bottom-sheet

I have created an app with a bottom sheet that utilizes bottom sheets with a list view.

Previously, I have used a `recyclerView` to show the list items from an array list, inside the bottom sheet. Now, I have changed the app to use a `listView` instead,  by retrieving data from a cursor.

Now, the bottom sheet only shows a single item:

[image: Emulator Image]

Even in the android studio preview, I can only see 1 list item:

I have created a test activity with a single list view, and all the data is shown except for the fact that every 3rd item is "distorted".

[image: Emulator Image]

Here is the code for the Layout Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinateLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"

    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:text="EventList Button"
            android:id="@+id/eventlistbutton"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            />
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/contactsbutton"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            android:id="@+id/contactsbutton"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/cardbackground2"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            />
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/zoomunpressed"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            android:id="@+id/zoomOut"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/cardbackground2"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:borderWidth="-120000dp"
            />
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/zoom2unpressed"
            android:id="@+id/zoomIn"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/cardbackground2"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:borderWidth="-120000dp"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/zoomOut"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/zoomOut"
            />
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/messageunpressed"
            android:id="@+id/chatbutton"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/cardbackground2"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/contactsbutton"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/contactsbutton" />
    </RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/bottomsheet"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/cardbackground"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Event List"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        />
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:background="@color/recyclerview_background"
        >
            <ListView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/eventlistview"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/recyclerviewhorizontalpadding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/recyclerviewhorizontalpadding"
                >
            </ListView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is the code for the Listview items:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/CardViewItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardbackground2"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/cardviewcorner"
    card_view:cardElevation="8dp"
    >
    <!--android:layout_marginTop="8dp"-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/cardbackground"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/event_name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:padding="@dimen/cardmargin"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:text="Museum Tour"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/event_date"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="@dimen/cardmargin"
                android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:text="8/24"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/card_view_height"
            android:background="@color/cardbackground2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/cardmargin"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text="Time:"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/event_time"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/cardmargin"
                    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    tools:text="11:50"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"

                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/cardmargin"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text="Summary:"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/event_summary"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:maxLength="130"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/cardmargin"
                    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
                    android:text="Once upon a time  a few missadfsafasdfasfdf"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/cardmargin"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text="Participants:"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/event_participantNum"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/cardmargin"
                    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
                    android:text="80"
                    android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/cardmargin"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text="Location:"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/event_location"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/cardmargin"
                    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
                    android:text="Rio de Janeiro"
                    android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Finally, here is the code for the Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    Button eventListButton;
    public static BottomSheetBehavior mBottomsheetbehvior;
    RecyclerView rv;
    LinearLayoutManager llm;
    Context context;
    public static GoogleMap mMap;
    FloatingActionButton contactsbutton;
    FloatingActionButton testButton;
    Intent contactsintent;
    Intent testIntent;

    DatabaseHelper eventsDBHelper;
    EventListCursorAdapter eventListCursorAdapter;
    Cursor eventCursor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myDataHolder dataHolder = new myDataHolder();
        context = this;

        eventsDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        LinearLayout bottomsheet =
                findViewById(R.id.bottomsheet);
        mBottomsheetbehvior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomsheet);
        mBottomsheetbehvior.setHideable(true);
        mBottomsheetbehvior.setPeekHeight(400);
        mBottomsheetbehvior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);

        eventListButton = findViewById(R.id.eventlistbutton);
        eventListButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(mBottomsheetbehvior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
                    mBottomsheetbehvior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
                    eventListButton.setText("Hide");
                }
                else if(mBottomsheetbehvior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED) {
                    mBottomsheetbehvior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
                    eventListButton.setText("Event List Button");
                }
                else if(mBottomsheetbehvior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
                    mBottomsheetbehvior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                    eventListButton.setText("Peek");
                }
            }
        });

        mBottomsheetbehvior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
                    eventListButton.setText("Peek");
                }
                else if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED) {
                    eventListButton.setText("Hide");
                }
                else if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
                    eventListButton.setText("Event List Button");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

            }
        }); 
        final ListView eventListView =  (ListView) findViewById(R.id.eventlistview);
        final DatabaseHelper eventManager = new DatabaseHelper(context);

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                eventCursor = eventManager.getAllEvents();
                eventListCursorAdapter = new EventListCursorAdapter(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        eventCursor,
                        0);

                eventListView.setAdapter(eventListCursorAdapter);
            }
        });
        thread.start();   
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        //Stuff
    }
    public void moveCamera(LatLng location){

        final CameraPosition movelocation  = CameraPosition.builder().
                target(location).zoom(14).build();
        MainActivity.mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(movelocation));
    }

}
```

If it helps, here is the code for the cursor adapter:

```
public class EventListCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater cursorInflater;
    Calculations calculations = new Calculations();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Context AppContext;

    public EventListCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);
        cursorInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        AppContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return cursorInflater.inflate(R.layout.card_view, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView timeText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_time);
        TextView nameText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_name);
        TextView dateText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_date);
        TextView summaryText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_summary);
        TextView participantsText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_participantNum);
        TextView locationText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_location);

        final Cursor mCursor = cursor;

        String date = calculations.UnixTimeConverter(
                mCursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_UNIXTIME)
        ))[0];
        String time = calculations.UnixTimeConverter(
                mCursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_UNIXTIME))
        )[1];
        final LatLng location = gson.fromJson(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_LOCATION)),LatLng.class);

        nameText.setText(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_NAME)));
        dateText.setText(date);
        timeText.setText(time);
        participantsText.setText(mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_PARTICIPANTS))+"");
        summaryText.setText(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_SUMMARY)));
        locationText.setText(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_LOCATIONNAME)));

        locationText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final CameraPosition camLocation  = CameraPosition.builder().
                        target(location).zoom(18).build();
                MainActivity.mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(camLocation));
            }
        });

        summaryText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                LayoutInflater mLayoutInflator;
                mLayoutInflator = LayoutInflater.from(AppContext);
                final AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                View mView = mLayoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.summarydialog,null);
                TextView textView = mView.findViewById(R.id.mainText);
                textView.setText(
                        mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_SUMMARY))
                );

                textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

                mBuilder.setView(mView);
                final AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

It will be helpful if you could tell how to have the bottom sheet listview show all of the data in the cursor, without having some of the list items being "distorted" like in the second image

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution.
Just remove the Nested ScrollView tag.
Apparently, you are not supposed to put a ListView inside of a scrollview

It will not cause any kind of behavorial changes to the bottom sheet :)